# Tikz pump symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

is there a symbol for pumps like the attached one? 
[image: Pump Symbol]

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is it for use with a specific package? Or you just want to draw the symbol somewhere in your document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy enough to make. One of many ways of doing so is a node style with a `path picture`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  pump/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    thick,
    minimum size=1cm,
    path picture={
      \draw [thick] (path picture bounding box.north) -- 
                    (path picture bounding box.east) --
                    (path picture bounding box.south);
      },
  node contents={}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[pump];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I haven't undestood if the OP want a symbol or a picture. Otherwise I remove my answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano Do whatever you want, I don't know more specifics about what the OP wanted than what you do.

Comment: I always believe in my humility and respect for others. My English is poor and I often do not answer questions that are actually simple. Then I did not understand why I got the green tick as yours is the best answer. My most sincere greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `TikZ`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\newcommand{\cirtri}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\draw [line width=.5pt] (0.,0.) circle (2.cm);
\draw [line width=.5pt] (0.,2.)-- (2.,0.);
\draw [line width=.5pt] (2.,0.)-- (0.,-2.);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
It is \cirtri{scale=.03mm} a new symbol.

\end{document}
```